# Algebra: make a the subject of $x(a+b)=a-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This isn't my homework, it's me trying to help my son

So, we have a series of questions with similar forms, the first of which is:

Make a the subject of:

$x(a+b)=a-1$

Maths isn't really my strong point, but I can complete simple operations on this equation:

$xa+xb+1=a$

$a+b=\dfrac{a-1}{x}$

$xb+1=a-xa$

However, I have tried, I can't work out how to isolate "a" so that there is only one. I would appreciate any pointers to techniques to solve this problem.

---

So, there have been lots of contributions, but I think that I am correct to say that none has identified the “missing” step that I could not pass. I am reminded of something I read in The Guardian a few days prior to asking this question:

> There is a belief among certain academics that a subject is less efficiently learned from an adept than from someone who is studying it or has just finished studying it. The adept’s long acquaintance makes it difficult for him or her to see the subject in its simpler terms or to appreciate what it is like to approach the subject as a greenhorn.

> https://www.theguardian.com/books/2022/aug/07/could-learning-algebra-in-my-60s-make-me-smarter-alec-wilkinson-a-divine-language-extract

Therefore, I will try to explain how I have come to understand how to solve this problem (and those like it).

**Make “a” the subject of:**

$x(a+b)=a-1$

*As an aside, I think it is more usual to ask the student to make “x” the subject, but I don’t suppose that matters too much…*

The relatively easy part here is getting all the “a”s on one side, and everything else on the other.

First step is to put “x” inside the brackets (that‘s “parentheses” to anyone speaking Americanese) and thus eliminate them.

$(xa+xb)=a-1$

Then:

$xa+xb=a-1$

I believe this is called “expanding” the equation.

I will explain why this is a logical step. Rather than taking the adept route, looking at the “$x(a+b)$” portion and saying:

$x(a+b)=xa+xb=x(a+b)$ *QED!*

I find that using “real” numbers actually illustrates the point in a concrete way:

$x=5, a=4, b=3$

$5(4+3)=35$

Step through it (using the BIDMAS route: https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/znmtsbk/articles/zj29dxs):

$5(7)=35$
$5*7=35$

Therefore, if we take the expanded version of “$5(4+3)=35$” we see the same result:

$5(4+3)=35$

$(5*4)+(5*3)=35$

$(20)+(15)=35$

$20+15=35$

You can substitute in any numbers you like to prove that (note, you can’t substitute in any numbers you like to resolve the whole equation, just to prove the logic of the steps you take):

$x(a+b)=xa+xb=x(a+b)$, so *QED!*

So, back to our first step:

$xa+xb=a-1$

The second step is to take “$xb$” and put it on the other side of the “=”:

$xa=a-xb-1$

To prove this with real numbers, we just need to have an equation that “balances” in the first place, and forget that we have “a” on both sides:

$5+4=10-1$ ie… $9=9$

$5=10-4-1$ … $5=6-1$ … $5=5$

I hope you are with me so far!

From $xa=a-xb-1$ we have to get “a” to the opposite side of the equation:

$xa=a-xb-1$

$xa-a=-xb-1$

We can prove this again using our “real” numbers:

$5=10-4-1$

$5-10=-4-1$

$-5=-5$

Now for the tricky part, @lulu writes in the comments:

> $a−xa=a(1−x)$

This part I really did not get at all, because there is obviously some intermediate step missing, but others are insisting that there is not.

There is a missing step, and this is it:

The part you have to complete is to factorise the lefthand side of the equation, let’s look at it:

$xa-a$

You take the  “a” in “xa” and put it outside some brackets:

$a(x…)$

Now, the standalone “a” was never multiplied by anything so if you put it in there you get something that is not logically correct:

$a(x-a)$ which if you expand you get $xa-aa$, so that cannot be correct. Instead, what you have to do is divide “a” by “a”:

$a(x-\dfrac{a}{a})$

We can demonstrate this again with real numbers:

a=4, x=5

**$xa-a$**

$(5*4)-4=16$ … $(20)-4=16$

**$a(x-\dfrac{a}{a})$:**

$4(5-\dfrac{4}{4})=16$ … $4(5-(1))=16$ … $4(4)=16$

So, then we prove that @lulu is correct, because any number divided by itself equals “1”:

$xa-a$ = $a(x-\dfrac{a}{a})$ = $a(x-1)$

We can also prove $a(x-1)$ = $xa-a$ by expanding $a(x-1)$:

$xa-1a$ “1a” is “a” so $xa-a$ is equal to $a(x-1)$

So, our equation is therefore:

$a(x-1)=-xb-1$

I think the next step is straightforward, in that we have to take the lefthand part in barackets, and use it to divide the righthand side, and thus isolate “a”:

$a=\dfrac{-xb-1}{x-1}$

Using real numbers again, we can prove that this is the next logical step:

$4*5=20$ … $4=\dfrac{20}{5}$

So, my answer is: **$a=\dfrac{-xb-1}{x-1}$**

Now I go back to the answer sheet, and the answer there is:

$a=\dfrac{bx+1}{1-x}$

Um, after all that, did I still get it wrong!?

I’ll step through it again… with a slightly different method…

$x(a+b)=a-1$

$xa+xb=a-1$

$xa+xb+1=a$

$xb+1=a-xa$

$xb+1=a(\dfrac{a}{a}-x)$

$xb+1=a(1-x)$

**$a=\dfrac{xb+1}{1-x}$**

Are both answers equivalent, or did I make a mistake the first time?

Comment: Note that $a-xa=a(1-x)$.

Comment: I am just curious. Where does that terminology come from? I have heard "solve for a" but never "make a the subject of...".

Comment: Seems quite common in GCSE maths in UK to say "make x the subject"

Comment: Lulu, you've lost me when "b" disappears!?

Comment: @lulu 's comment is "factoring". It's just the opposite of what you did in your first step.

Comment: @JohnDouma: See here, for example: https://thirdspacelearning.com/gcse-maths/algebra/make-x-the-subject/, https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/z36vcj6/revision/4

Comment: The $b$ has not vanished, it's still comfortably sitting on the left.  I was rewriting the right hand, so now we get $xb+1=a(1-x)$ and it is easy to solve that for $a$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you for the link but that just says it means the same thing as "to solve for". I am trying to make sense of that statement. Does the right hand side have a name? Can you diagram an equation like a sentence?

Comment: @JohnDouma It’s basically a short form of “Write so-and-so in terms of so-and-so”.

Comment: Also don't forget the case $x=1$. Then your equation is $(a+b)=a-1$, which says nothing about $a$. However, it gives $b=-1$.

Comment: @lulu, sure, that's "simple", and results in a=(xb+1)/(x-1), which I know is the answer because I have the answer sheet. I just don' t understand how you get to the previous step.

Comment: I was just trying to illustrate the comment about this being common in the UK. Anyway, I suppose one could interpret the word "subject" in this case as "the thing being talked about". But it would be interesting to know if this terminology is some old-fashioned remnant, or a modern thing invented by math educators, or what.

Comment: FWIW I had never heard of "Make $a$ the subject" but it does indeed appear to mean exactly what we yanks would call "Solve for $x$".  And it logically makes sense to me.  "subject" = "thing being talked about"... a little more english than math but, hey,.... it's not meaningless or bizarre.  And if other countries say it regularly who am I to say "Durn it, talk Amurican, you ferrinors!"

Comment: I encourage typonaut, who has "the answer sheet", to edit what was shared in a Comment above into the body of the Question.  This would very much help Readers to understand what is being asked of them.

Comment: Ok, I think I have worked it out, and summarised, above.

Answer (score 4):

Do everything you can to get the $a$s to one side of an equation and everything else to the other.

$x(a+b)=a-1$
$xa + xb = a-1$

So get everything that has anything to do with $a$ onto one side (say the LHS but it doesn't really matter which) and get everything that doesn't have anything to do with $a$ onto the other side.

$\underbrace{xa}_{\text{something to do with }a} + \underbrace{xb}_{\text{nothing to do with }a}=\underbrace{a}_{\text{something to do with }a} - \underbrace{1}_{\text{nothing to do with }a}$

You have something to do with $a$ on the right hand side.  Get it to the left hand side.
You have something that doesn't have anything to do with $a$ on the left hand side.  Get it to the right hand side.

$\underbrace{xa}_{\text{something to do with }a} -\underbrace{a}_{\text{something to do with }a} = - \underbrace{1}_{\text{nothing to do with }a}-\underbrace{xb}_{\text{nothing to do with }a}$

Can you finish up from there?

> Hint: factor
>
>  $a(x-1) = -1 -xb$

> And divide
>
>   $a = \frac {-1-xb}{x-1}$
>
>   (It is important to know that we are assuming $x \ne 1$.  If $x = 1$ we can not solve for $a$.... If $x=1$ we have $a+b = a-1$ and we can conclude $b=-1$ but $a$ could be *anything*.)

Comment: Do you think OP needs to solve this equation for $x$, not for $a$? Maybe, OP is confused..

Comment: Possibly.  I don't know what "make $a$ the subject of" means or how it'd tie in with solving for $x$.  We'd have $x = \frac {a-1}{a+b} = 1 -\frac {b+1}{a+b}$ which is an expression with only one $a$ but... I'm not sure I see the point of such.

Comment: OP is confused, but not about the purpose of the question: the task is to make “a” the subject.

Comment: Apart from having everything around the other way from me (ie I have: xb+1=a-xa), the point I lose the thread at is your first “spoiler”. Yes, I can factorise a(x-1) back to xa-a, I just can’t conceptualise the step going the other way – which is the core problem. My guess is that you are dividing "a" by "a” – "x-(a/a)" – where (a/a) is obviously "1". But not quite getting the inbetween steps!?

Comment: If $a(x-1) = xa -a$ (that's not factoring by the way; its expanding) then $xa-a = a(x-1)$.  Things are what the are and the can't be different things just because you derived them in a different order.  Factoring (which is pulling things apart) is a necessary art that all math doers must learn and be comfortable.  But okay.... You have $xa$ and that has an $a$ in it and you have $a$ and that has an $a$ in it.  And if you have a same with $a$s in both term you can "undistribute" them  $m(n+p) = mn + mp$ by distribution.  But that means $mn + mp = m(n+p)$ just looking in the other direction....

Comment: .... so there *is* no in-between steps.  It's just that $xa = x \cdot a$ and $a = 1\cdot a$ so we have $x\cdot a + 1\cdot a$ and we can pull the $a$ out (And that **IS** what factoring is).  You just pull it out:  $x\cdot a + 1\cdot a = (x+1)\cdot a$.  If $a(x+1) = ax +a$ then the reverse *HAS* to be true.  $ax+a = a(x+1)$.  Going from $a(x+1)\to ax + a$ is *expanding* (or *distributing*) .  And going from $ax + a=a\cdot x + a\cdot 1\to a(x+1)$ is *factoring*.  It's *very important to get comfortable with that.

Comment: If Michael = Peter's father  then we *have* to have Peter's father = Michael.  We can't have *I* am fleabood, but fleablodd isn't me.  And likewise if $a(x+1) =ax + a$ then we *have* to have $ax+a = a(x+1)$.  We can't have it only go one way.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x = \frac{a-1}{a+b} $$
says that $x$  is the result of a Moebius transformation of $a,$  coefficient matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1& -1 \\
1 & b
\end{array}
\right)
$$
So, with the adjoint matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
b& 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we find
$$  a = \frac{bx+1}{-x+1}  $$

Comment: IMO, I think OP doesn't know about Moebius transformation and Matrix, determinant etc.  These things already exceed even high-school knowledge.

Comment: As Frank Abagnale Jr says “I concur” (with @User)